# WinAppDeployCmd - Access denied even with PIN

Tags: deployment, windows-10-mobile

I am attempting to deploy an app to a phone running Windows 10 Mobile (build 10.0.10586.164) using [WinAppDeployCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203806.aspx). I have pulled up the window to pair the device with a PIN, but entering that PIN is not working. For example, the following command gives an error.

```
C:\Users\Hodor\>WinAppDeployCmd.exe install -file app_1.0.0.0_arm.appxbundle -ip 192.168.1.132 -pin L8J4d2

Windows App Deployment Tool
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Opening connection to device at '192.168.1.132'.

Access denied while connecting to the remote device.
Please retry the command with the "-pin" option and a valid pin as shown in the device settings.
The pin is a one time requirement to establish a pairing relationship with the device.
```

I am able to ping the phone with no issue. I am able to deploy the app over USB, but am trying to setup a CI solution right now to deploy to several phones automatically on a successful build.

Is there a step that I am missing? I successfully used WinAppDeployCmd last summer with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what worked for me was to use the `-guid` parameter instead of the `-ip` parameter to specify the target.

Use the `WinAppDeployCmd devices` command to find the guid of the device you want to target.

Then, run `WinAppDeployCmd` just with `-guid` instead of `-ip`:

`C:\Users\Hodor\>WinAppDeployCmd.exe install -file app_1.0.0.0_arm.appxbundle -guid <guid> -pin L8J4d`